# Installing PHP+ Apache on netbeans

Tags: php, apache, netbeans-6.9

I need help with this issue. I'm trying to install php in my netbeans but i dont know exactly how to do it. The netbeans version i'v downloaded already have PHP installed (i can create a php project). But, for some reason when i run the project, nothing happens. I dont really think i have Apache Tomcat installed in my netbeans, that what i need help for. When adding the "tomcat 6.0" server, this information is needed:

server location (catalina home)

username

password

I have no idea what is that. I would apreciate help on this - How to install PHP + ApacheTomcat on neatbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Tomcat is for running Java apps. You'll be wanting [Apache HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org/) instead.

I've always kept the installation of Apache and netbeans separate, I would:

1. Install Apache on your system - doesn't matter if Windows or Linux, just follow install instructions.
2. Find out the Apache directory that you will add your php files into. That's usually /var/www/ on Linux, don't know about Windows.
3. Create a new PHP project in Netbeans and configure it to use sources from the Apache directory in #2. Say for a project called teststuff I create a dir called /var/www/teststuff/ and create a Netbeans project inside there.

You should be able to browse to http://localhost to see your new server running.